# Saxon transformation is failed with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error

Tags: amazon-s3, xslt, streaming, saxon

I am trying to transform the big file of around 13 GB  with the streaming feature in the SAXON EE library.
And trying to store the transformed result into the stream then send this streamed data to S3.

If I use the ByteArrayOutputStream object to store the StreamResult from the trans.transform(streamSource, new StreamResult(output_stream)) method, I am getting out of memory error.

```
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -DentityExpansionLimit=0 -DtotalEntitySizeLimit=0 -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=0 "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=55781:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/gobinathgopalsamy/IdeaProjects/saxon-transform-poc/out/production/saxon-transform-poc:/Users/gobinathgopalsamy/Downloads/SaxonEE10-5J/saxon-ee-10.5.jar TransformWorker
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.UTF8Writer.write(UTF8Writer.java:292)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.UTF8Writer.write(UTF8Writer.java:259)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.writeEscape(XMLEmitter.java:895)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.writeAttribute(XMLEmitter.java:589)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.attribute(XMLEmitter.java:503)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.startElement(XMLEmitter.java:423)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceDifferencer.startElement(NamespaceDifferencer.java:71)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.startElement(ProxyReceiver.java:139)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.SequenceNormalizer.startElement(SequenceNormalizer.java:84)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.startElement(ComplexContentOutputter.java:530)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyOutputter.startElement(ProxyOutputter.java:108)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyOutputter.startElement(ProxyOutputter.java:108)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyOutputter.startElement(ProxyOutputter.java:108)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyOutputter.startElement(ProxyOutputter.java:108)
    at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyElementImpl.copy(TinyElementImpl.java:389)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.feed.ComplexNodeEventFeed.append(ComplexNodeEventFeed.java:86)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.adjunct.BlockAdjunct$BlockFeed.append(BlockAdjunct.java:100)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.watch.ForEachAction$$Lambda$78/1204296383.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:136)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.watch.ForEachAction.append(ForEachAction.java:169)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.feed.NoOpenOrCloseFeed.append(NoOpenOrCloseFeed.java:38)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.feed.ItemFeed$$Lambda$77/405896924.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:136)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.feed.ItemFeed.processItems(ItemFeed.java:113)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.feed.AbsorptionFeed.endSelectedParentNode(AbsorptionFeed.java:86)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.watch.Trigger.endSelectedParentNode(Trigger.java:101)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.watch.WatchManager.endElement(WatchManager.java:527)
    at com.saxonica.ee.stream.ContentDetector.endElement(ContentDetector.java:47)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Sample code.

```
import com.saxonica.config.StreamingTransformerFactory;
import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;

import net.sf.saxon.s9api.*;

import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

public class TransformWorker {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws TransformerException, SaxonApiException {
        File file = new File("files/feed.xml"); // this is 13 GB file
        Source streamSource = new StreamSource(file);       
        TransformerFactory factory =new StreamingTransformerFactory();
        Configuration config = ((TransformerFactoryImpl)factory).getConfiguration();
        config.isLicensedFeature(Configuration.LicenseFeature.ENTERPRISE_XSLT);
        factory.setAttribute("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/licenseFileLocation","saxon-license.lic");
        File sheet = new File("files/feed.xsl");        
        Templates templates = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(sheet));     

        ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Transformer trans =templates.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.ENCODING.toString(),"UTF-8");       
        trans.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD.toString(),"xml");
        trans.transform(streamSource, new StreamResult(output_stream)); 
        // send the stream result to S3
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: So the input is 13 GB, what kind of output size do you expect to create from that that you want to put into the ByteArrayOutputStream? It looks as if your Java code is not running out of memory streaming through the huge input XML but rather while writing (parts of) the output to that ByteArrayOutputStream. I am not familiar with the infrastructure you mention (S3, Amazon), is there no way to write directly to a FileOutputStream? Can you run the transformation fine with Saxon EE from the command line? It might help to add a tag for Amazon/S3 to see whether people know how to write huge content

Comment: What does `send the stream result to S3` do exactly, is that not a HTTP PUT with a request stream you could construct the StreamResult over?

Comment: @MartinHonnen  If I use FileOutputStream it writes files to disk then I need to read the file again to send to S3. Is there a better way to do this without writing the file and then read the content?

Comment: I am not familiar with S3 so I don't know what your comment `// send the stream result to S3` refers to and whether or how it would be possible to not use a ByteArrayOutputStream. It seems there is some REST PUT API for S3, not sure whether you can use a StreamResult over the request stream of the body of such a PUT request. I hope someone else can tell, now that the tag for Amazon-S3 has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Like Martin, I don't know much about the S3 APIs. The Saxon streaming transformation seems to be working; the problem is streaming the result into S3. From what I can see, Amazon's PutObjectRequest allows you to supply a File or an InputStream, and I guess what you're doing is writing the data to a memory buffer so you can then connect an input stream to that buffer. But there isn't enough memory for the buffer.

One solution would be to buffer the data on disk instead of in memory by using a File.

Another solution would be to use two threads: have Saxon write to a `PipedOutputStream` in one thread while your Amazon upload reads from the corresponding `PipedInputStream` in the other. (Again, I'm afraid I don't have any personal experience of using these classes. There's a little tutorial describing them at https://flylib.com/books/en/1.134.1/communicating_between_threads_using_piped_streams.html)